# (React Native) Как взять cookie из WebView?

Tags: android, ios, cookie, webview, react-native

Есть некий url который прогружается в WebView при запуске приложения, пользователь совершает вход и кука обновляется, к ней прибавляется токен и прочие данные авторизующие сессию пользователя.

Существует механизм взятия этой куки для дальнейшей работы с ней используя fetch()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100086/android-extracting-cookies-after-login-in-webview вот тут посмотрите

Comment: @АндроидАндроид с react-native там связи нет, но все равно спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во время использования модуля **WebView**, возможно отправлять запросы серверу через **fetch()**

Например: Если произведен вход в аккаунт на каком-то сайте, то куки сохраняются и во время сессии можно делать запросы через **fetch()** и манипулировать данными.

Алгоритм наглядно показан в этом репозитории с использованием библиотеки [react-native-cookies](https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies):

- https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/react-native-login